# Why sigmoid will make gradient all positive or negative

Tags: machine-learning

In the course cs231n, when I go through the note about activation function, I meet a problem about sigmoid function. Here is the screen shot:

[cons and pros of sigmoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDbMj.png)

In my opinion, since the gradient `dw = x.T dot dout`, although now `x.T` is all positive, but after matrix multiplication, why `dw` will be all positive or negative? the only chance of that is that `dout` is all positive or negative, but why is that?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the exact sentence, in its entirety it says (slightly paraphrased):

> If the data coming into a neuron is always positive then the gradient on the weights during backpropagation become either all positive or all negative (depending on the gradient of the whole expression f).

Assume `f = w^Tx + b`. Then the gradients with respect to the weights is `\nabla_w L = (dL/df)(df/dw)`. Since `dL/df` is a scalar, it is either positive or negative (or zero, but that is unlikely). On the other hand, 
`df/dw = x`. So clearly if `x` is all positive or all negative, then `df/dw` is also all positive or all negative. But this means that `\nabla_w L` must also be all positive or all negative, because `dL/df` cannot change the signs of individual elements of  `df/dw` differently. Thus the sign of the gradient is homogeneous.

Comment: Do you mean there is a premise that f is a scalar? Then df/dw = x^T, dL/dw = dL/df*df/dw = dL/df * x^T, since all x^T > 0, so that dL/dw is either positve or negative since dL/df is a scalar. 
But what if f is not a scalar, that means, X is of N x D and W is D x C, then dL/dW = X^T $\cdot$ dL/df, even though X^T is all positive, dL/df contains both positive and negative, then dL/dW may contains both positive and negative.